# How to update other field based on email id in fire store android

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

[image]

This is my fire store database i am trying to update phone number based on email id .
below code i am trying to updated phone

```
firebaseFirestore.collection("Users")
                        .document("anilkt87@gmail.com")
                        .update("phone",897389121 );
```

but i am unable to update i am new in fire store can any one help me in this.

Comment: You will need [query using a filter](https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/query-data/queries#simple_queries) on the email field to get the document ID, then [update that document](https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/manage-data/add-data#update-data).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ```
> firebaseFirestore.collection("Users")
>                             .document("anilkt87@gmail.com")
>                             .update("phone",897389121 );
> ```

This code mean you are operate a document that id is `anilkt87@gmail.com`, But it is a field value in you screenshot not id, In this scenario you have to run query first, Then update those documents.

Comment: Thanks for helping can you please tell me what query i have to update i am unable to find code for that

Comment: See this document https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#simple_queries, Query basically means you are asking documents in a collention in certain condition